# Explain what is happening with RotateTo with different X and Y?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

RotateTo comes with two create methods - one which lets you specify only a single angle to rotate to, and another where one can specify a different angle for X and Y.

I don't understand what is going on when you use the latter (specifying angles for both X and Y). In the form, its just that the same angle is used for both.

Can someone explain what is actually going on when you specify two different angles, and the situation when this would actually be useful ? I've tried it out, but I can't figure out how this is useful ?

EDIT: I'm aware that the output using different x,y vs same looks different. I've actually tried it out myself. My question is - what's the point ? In which situation is it useful?

Answer (score 1):

There are difference's between giving single angle and two different x and y. For Single we are giving an angle for example 90° , In case of the second We will give separate angle for both x and y to create an action. The look of animation differs from both. Usage of them actually depends on your project needs.

For Eg If you code like below

Single Angle :- `CCFiniteTimeAction* actionRotate1 = CCRotateTo::create(6.0, 90);`

or

Different x and y Angle :- `CCFiniteTimeAction* actionRotate1 = CCRotateTo::create(6.0, 90,90);`

The output will be like this

[90° Output](http://screencast.com/t/HCp1Jfy1kDFh)

But when you give different angle the difference between the animations can be felt for giving single angle and giving different angle's for x and y.

Single Angle :- `CCFiniteTimeAction* actionRotate1 = CCRotateTo::create(6.0, 540);`

The output is :- [Single Angle Output](http://screencast.com/t/Okmhmx0Uh2)

Different x and y Angle :- `CCFiniteTimeAction* actionRotate1 = CCRotateTo::create(6.0,0,540);`

The output is  :- [Different x and y Output](http://screencast.com/t/jwL3qe2I)

You can feel the animation changes when we give different angles for both x and y. It gives you `flip like animation` look but in case of single angle, the specified images is just rotated to the desired angle.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm aware that it looks different. I've actually tried it out myself. My question is - what's the point ? In which situation is it useful?